# what JPA provider does JBOSS application server ships with?

Tags: jakarta-ee, jpa, jboss, glassfish

I search online to find if `JBOSS` application server ships with any `JPA` implementations.
I came up with hits such as `Hibernate, EclipseLink` etc. But I am not sure if these are shipped with `JBOSS` or added in configuration files by downloading external jars and adding in classpath.

what I mean by ship is:

`JBOSS application server` comes with `RESTeasy` which is the provider for `JAX-RS API`. To get the server up and running, I do NOT need any other jars such as `Jersey` etc.

On the same Note, I heard `GlassFish application server` ships with `providers` for various J2EE components such as `JTA, JPA , JAX-RS`. but I am wondering how to know the `implementations` or `providers` for these.

Thanks

Comment: It works with all of the main JPA providers irrespective of what is included (so works with, for example, what I use DataNucleus). See https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS72/JPA+Reference+Guide

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far that I know it uses the Hibernate:

https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JPA+Reference+Guide

> During application deployment, JPA use is detected (e.g. persistence.xml or @PersistenceContext/Unit annotations) and injects Hibernate dependencies into the application deployment. This makes it easy to deploy JPA applications.

Comment: do you still use `persistence.xml` if one uses `hibernate`. I thought hibernate uses `hibernate.cfg.xml`

Comment: persistence.xml is needed if you want to use the JPA API only. hibernate.cfg.xml is used when you want to use hibernate features that are not in JPA API.

Comment: so do I specify in `persistence.xml` that the provider is `hibernate` or since it is shipped with JBOSS I don't need to specify it?

Comment: There is only one way to answer that, just try to do it without it and see what it happens, and later do it with it. I have seen some versions working without it and others only with it.